# When does $\|p\|_k$ define a norm on $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

> Consider the real vector space $V$ of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $d$. For $p \in V$ define  $$\lVert p\rVert_k = \mathrm {max} \{\lvert p(0)\rvert,\lvert p^{(1)}(0)\rvert,\dots,\lvert p^{(k)}(0)\rvert \},$$ where $p^{(i)}(0)$ is the $i^{\mathrm {th}}$ derivative of $p$ evaluated at $0$. Then $\lVert p\rVert_k$ defines a norm on $V$ if and only if
>
> $1. \ $ $k \ge d-1$.
>
> $2. \ $ $k < d$.
>
> $3. \ $ $k \ge d$.
>
> $4. \ $ $k < d-1$.

How can I proceed to solve this question? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What means $p^k(0)$? Derivative, power?

Comment: What properties does a norm need to verify?

Comment: @Jonas Lenz first thing we have to verify is that $\|p\|_k \ge 0$ for any $p$ and $\|p\|_k=0$ if and only if $p=0$. Then we have to verify whether or not $\|ap\|_k=|a|\|p\|_k$ for any $a \in \Bbb R$. At last we have to verify the triangle inequality. Isn't it so?

Comment: Indeed. As a possible start, what does it mean if the i-th derivative of a polynomial vanishes as $0$?

Comment: @D_C A good place to start would be definiteness ($\|p\|_k = 0 \implies p = 0$). If $k = 1$, then assuming $\|p\|_1 = 0$ will only tell you the polynomial goes through $0$. If your polynomial is constant, that's great! If not, then it could be non-zero, which is bad!

Comment: The second property clearly holds for any $k$. Also $\|p\|_k\ge 0$ for any $p$ and for any $k$. But I am quite confused at the stage about whether $\|p\|_k=0$ if and only if $p=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that $p(x)=x^d$ is non-zero polynomial of degree $d$ such that $p^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,1,\dots,d-1$. Then show that if $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^d a_i x^i$ then $p^{(k)}(0)=k!a_k$ for $k=0,1,\dots,d$. Is there a non-zero polynomial $p$ of degree $\leq d$ such that $p^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,1,\dots,d$?

Comment: No. It can't be. Because there exists $0 \le k \le d$ such that the $k^{\mathrm {th}}$ derivative of $p$ is a non-zero constant.

Comment: So what may we conclude?

Comment: So $\|p\|_k=0$ if and only if $p=0$. Oh! great.

Comment: So $k \ge d$. Isn't it so?

Comment: But what about the triangle inequality?

Comment: Well this is the only option, but you have to verify also the other properties.

Comment: Note that $\max_k|(p+q)^{(k)}(0)|=\max_k|p^{(k)}(0)+q^{(k)}(0)|\leq \max_k(|p^{(k)}(0)|+|q^{(k)}(0)|)\leq ?$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah! Sure.  Actually I have done it (triangle inequality part) myself before you have commented about it. Thank you very much @Robert Z for your kind help.